# How to catch an output of .exe command that opens in another cmd?

Tags: windows, cmd, pid

I need to open an .exe program and write its output to a file.

Command in cmd goes like this:

`program.exe listLicenses > output.txt`

I tried redirecting all of the output of **program.exe** in the file by its PID, but then I get only bunch of hieroglyphs when I run a command again.

Part of the problem is that the command opens a new cmd in new window, so I can't see an output at all and I am connected over SSH to a machine (Windows machine) on which I execute the command.
Content of the output should be only a License key in xml format.

I need it to automate some builds.

Edit:
I can connect via RDP protocol on said Windows machine and do it by hand but then I'll disconnect other user that is connected.

Comment: You can try `program.exe listLicenses ^> "%temp%\output.txt"`, which *should* create a file on the destination machine, which you then can view or copy to your local system.

Comment: @Stephan I tried your solution but it doesn't work. https://www.flickr.com/photos/198128296@N05 You can see the snip of outputs and commands in flickr.

Comment: You said, there was a file, but "unreadable". I didn't find any help for the program online (except the suggestion to use the built-in help with `/?`) Check if there are any switches to format the output. It's probably an encoding problem (`cmd` can't handle Unicode very well)

Comment: @Stephan I get that file only if I redirect all of the output of **program.exe** to the file but what I want is to redirect only `program.exe /listLicenses` to the file but program.exe opens a new CMD on the machine I am connected to whisch is detached from my cmd, so I can't catch it's output.